# Previously (non-)upvoted comment doesn't show the (non-)upvote received anymore

Tags: bug, comments, up-votes

I'm *positive* that an *apparent* upvote on a [comment of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614871/what-software-that-supported-by-windows-xp-can-not-run-on-xubuntu#comment866297_614871) it's not there anymore: after having left the comment, I was still in the page to read one of the answers a second time when I saw it got upvoted.

A few minutes later the question was at the top of the active questions and I visited it again: no upvote on the comment now, as you can see, but I've noticed that the top answer has been upvoted once more in the meantime (from 2 to 3 upvotes).

I'm *positive* that the comment appeared as upvoted before I left the page the first time.

I also reloaded the page multiple times, the upvote is still not there anymore.

My speculation is there's something wrong with the JavaScript / AJAX code in the page.

Comment: You realize that the person who cast the comment upvote can remove it later right? Maybe they changed their mind or accidentally upvoted it when they didn't mean to.

Comment: @Seth I've never been able to remove any upvote on any comment, but now I guess that I could have within some sort of grace period?

Comment: Yes, there is a grace period, although I do not know how long it is. I would guess something like 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: @Seth Didn't know about that, it's indeed more reasonable than to not allow to remove downvotes at all (which is how i tought it worked). Makes way more sense, thanks

Comment: You can remove downvotes too within 5 minutes of casting them or if the post was edited since you voted.

Comment: @Seth Thanks, actually I've never noticed this as well.